# Confusion related enum object allocation in JVM

Tags: java

This might be a stupid question, but I am really confused after Googling.

We have a very big Java EE application. Now when it's time to go to production, there are a number of performance related problems raised. I am trying to get to the bottom of a memory leak issue. When I was looking through JProfiler, I found some enum variables that will not be garbage collected.

Just an example:

The application has one session factory, which is a kind of map i.e. `Map<SessionKey, Object>`. When the user is logged in that map will fill up and it will be cleared when that user logs out.

But with JProfiler I encountered some strange behavior. It shows `SessionKey` memory allocation  increasing with the number of logins. When I'm logged in for the first time it shows **106 difference** and after the second login it shows **206 difference** in JProfiler. So this means the difference is increasing and increases more frequently.

**is it enum never eligible for garbage collection?**

I could not get it that what is wrong in it. Or I understand wrong. Let me know for more detail.

```
public enum SessionKey{
    LOGGEDIN_USER, DOCUMENT_ID, LOGGEDIN_USER_POSTS, LOGGEDIN_USER_PRIVILEGE, NORM_ID, DOCUMENT_REF_NO,DOCUMENT_STATUS, DOCUMENT,APPLICANT_USER, 
    NORM, CLIENT_SESSION_EXPIRED,  
    GININJECTOR, SCHEDULE_ID, DOCUMENT_ENTITY_TYPE,SOURCE_DOCUMENT_ID, CONFIGURATION_LIST, LOGGEDIN_USER_ID, 
    SOURCE_NORM_ID, MASKING_PANEL, IS_ETOKEN, 
    LOGGEDIN_USER_PRIVILEGE_NAMES, LOGGEDIN_USER_PRIVILEGE_IDS, IPADDRESS, AUTO_COMPLETE_SCHEDULER,
    MESSAGES, DEFAULT_CERTIFICATE, DOCUMENT_FORM_MAP,DOCUMENT_FORM_FCM_MAP,DOCTYPELIST,ACCESS_RIGHT,LOGGEDIN_USER_DEFAULT_POST,LAST_LOGIN_DETAILS, DOC_STATUS_ENUM_MASTERS
    ,MODULE_RIGHT_ENUM_MASTERS,MODULE_RIGHT, LOGGEDIN_USER_DEFAULT_PORTAL,
    LOGGEDIN_USER_DEFAULT_POST_MAP,HISTORY_CLEAR,DOC_DETAILS_PORTAL,ORGANIZATION_ID, DOCUMENT_DETAILS_FROM_JSP,PORTAL_MAP,ORGANIZATION,
    CONFIGURATION_MAP, DEFAULT_SIGN_CERTIFICATE,SYSTEM_VERSION,
    IS_LOGGEDIN_IN_ORGANIZATION, SUPPLIER_PORTAL_BASED_ON_URL, SUPPLIER_ORGANIZATION_BASED_ON_URL, BEFORE_LOGIN, USER_LANGUAGE, SERVER_DATE_TIME,DOCUMENTTYPE_CONFIG_TABLE;
}
```

SessionFacory code:

```
public class SessionFactory {
    private static HashMap session;
    public static HashMap getClientSessionInstance() {
        if (session == null) {
            session = new HashMap();
        }
        return session;
    }

    public static Object getValue(SessionKey key) {
        return getClientSessionInstance().get(key);
    }

    public static void putValue(SessionKey key, Object value) {

        getClientSessionInstance().put(key, value);
    }

    public static void remove(SessionKey key) {
        getClientSessionInstance().remove(key);
    }

    public static void clear() {
        getClientSessionInstance().remove(SessionKey.LOGGEDIN_USER);
        getClientSessionInstance().remove(SessionKey.LOGGEDIN_USER_PRIVILEGE);
        getClientSessionInstance().remove(SessionKey.LOGGEDIN_USER_ID);
        getClientSessionInstance().remove(SessionKey.LOGGEDIN_USER_POSTS);
        getClientSessionInstance().remove(SessionKey.CONFIGURATION_LIST);
        getClientSessionInstance().remove(SessionKey.DOCUMENTTYPE_CONFIG_TABLE);
        getClientSessionInstance().remove(SessionKey.SERVER_DATE_TIME);
        getClientSessionInstance().remove(SessionKey.USER_LANGUAGE);
        getClientSessionInstance().remove(SessionKey.SUPPLIER_ORGANIZATION_BASED_ON_URL);
        getClientSessionInstance().remove(SessionKey.SUPPLIER_PORTAL_BASED_ON_URL);
        getClientSessionInstance().remove(SessionKey.IS_LOGGEDIN_IN_ORGANIZATION);
        getClientSessionInstance().remove(SessionKey.DEFAULT_SIGN_CERTIFICATE);
        getClientSessionInstance().remove(SessionKey.CONFIGURATION_MAP);
        getClientSessionInstance().remove(SessionKey.ORGANIZATION);
        getClientSessionInstance().remove(SessionKey.LOGGEDIN_USER_DEFAULT_PORTAL);

        getClientSessionInstance().remove(SessionKey.ACCESS_RIGHT);
        getClientSessionInstance().remove(SessionKey.DOC_STATUS_ENUM_MASTERS);
        getClientSessionInstance().remove(SessionKey.IS_ETOKEN);

        getClientSessionInstance().remove(SessionKey.ORGANIZATION_ID);

        getClientSessionInstance().remove(SessionKey.LAST_LOGIN_DETAILS);
        getClientSessionInstance().remove(SessionKey.LOGGEDIN_USER_DEFAULT_POST);
        getClientSessionInstance().remove(SessionKey.MODULE_RIGHT);
        getClientSessionInstance().remove(SessionKey.MASKING_PANEL);
        getClientSessionInstance().remove(SessionKey.GININJECTOR);
        getClientSessionInstance().remove(SessionKey.MODULE_RIGHT_ENUM_MASTERS);
        getClientSessionInstance().remove(SessionKey.LOGGEDIN_USER_DEFAULT_POST_MAP);


        clearDocumentSession();

    }

    public static void clearDocumentSession() {
        getClientSessionInstance().remove(SessionKey.DOCUMENT_ID);
        getClientSessionInstance().remove(SessionKey.DOCUMENT_REF_NO);
        getClientSessionInstance().remove(SessionKey.DOCUMENT_STATUS);
        getClientSessionInstance().remove(SessionKey.DOCUMENT);
        getClientSessionInstance().remove(SessionKey.APPLICANT_USER);
        getClientSessionInstance().remove(SessionKey.NORM);
        getClientSessionInstance().remove(SessionKey.NORM_ID);
        getClientSessionInstance().remove(SessionKey.SCHEDULE_ID);
        if(getClientSessionInstance().containsKey(SessionKey.SOURCE_DOCUMENT_ID))
            getClientSessionInstance().remove(SessionKey.SOURCE_DOCUMENT_ID);
        if(getClientSessionInstance().containsKey(SessionKey.SOURCE_NORM_ID))
            getClientSessionInstance().remove(SessionKey.SOURCE_NORM_ID);
    }

}
```

Comment: apart from the `SessionFactory` is there any place where `SessionKey` is getting used and still holds a ref?

Comment: Could you provide some example code? Is SessionKey your enum? Are you using EnumMap? ... It would help me to understand your question better.

Comment: @AjayGeorge This session factory used throughout application, and that key is used inside it only. but I remove from it while user logged out.

Comment: Other than mutable statics eurgh, it might be worth noting that this is thread-hostile.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline can you tell me more about it. sorry but I could not getting it. can you give some hint how can I overcome from this issue..

Comment: As an aside, enums come with a method called [`values()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) which give you all of the types for easy iteration.  That would reduce your entire clear code logic to about four lines, tops.

Answer (score 4):

enum objects are like static variables of applications. They are not garbage collected.

Comment: Thanks, than what is solution for it.what should I use instead of it. I am more concern with readability and manageable code.

Comment: and also one confution. if static then it will create once only. while it will create again and again. may be java class loader load it  again and again..what is root cause of it. confuse!!

Comment: I think enum is not your real problem because as I said earlier, enum objects are like static variables. So you can't create any new objects of enum. When you say getClientSessionInstance().put(key, value) , you are actually just making a new reference. So I don't think enum is your real problem...

Comment: sorry bro..cant help you with that..I have never used jprofiler. Wait for some expert to answer your question. :)

Answer (score 1):

enum defined entries are static instance of the defined enum.

in more clear way the java compiler generate a bytecode that match a code like:

```
public class SessionKey {
    public static final SessionKey LOGGEDIN_USER = new SessionKey();
    .....
}
```

so, the instances of enum will never collected by the garbage collector because are static instance, and also the number of instance of your enum "SessionKey" will never change on all life of your running VM, probably the problem is not related to the enum and sometime the profilers give just a sample of instances status.

to be complete there's only one time that the enum instances can be unloaded, and is when the classloader of the enum unload the enum ;) like all static instances !!

Comment: Thanks, but one confusion here same question I asked @nitin hope you may have answer. if static then it will create once only. while it will create again and again. may be java class loader load it again and again..what is root cause of it. confuse!!

Comment: i think the source of mistake is the way how work of the profiler, i never used jprofiler but i usually use jvisulvm or yourkit, and i know that tool are not tracking all instances but sampling the memory and that can be source of wrong count, try to check the option of jprofile for force it to track all, about the classloader if you are in an application server and you are not redeploying the application should be only one for the web application with only the listed instances of enum, if you are playing a bit  with AOP or with classloader can happen to have different behaviour!

Answer (score 0):

The enum should not be your problem. As the other answers are explaining they are only instantiated once. Or are you doing some strange things with a classloader?

The problem might come from your session HashMap. Since it is static and you only access it with getClientSessionInstance() there should be (although it's not thread save) only one in the application. One Problem might occur is that somewhere in the aplication getClientSessionInstance() is called and something is inserted in the map. Since your HashMap is not typed, anything could be inserted as key and your clear() function will not remove it. Why not calling clear() on the HashMap? I suggest using EnumMap or at least HashMap and make your getClientSessionInstance() function private.

Something that interests me: Don't you want to have a session map for each user or is this running on a client jvm?

Comment: yes, this code is running on a client jvm..sorry I forgot to mention this code inside gwt package code..after compile it will convert in javascript.

Comment: so the enum is only used in javascript? but your memory problem is on the server right?